# CheckPixelColor on thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winapi

I have a function that checks the color at specified positions (using GetPixel from winapi) for very short period of time(50 ms).
Right now I use a timer on the form to call that function every 50 ms, but my application freezes like hell.

How do I make it in a separate thread that repeats itself to infinity so that it doesn't freeze the user interface?

Answer (score 4):

I'd have to recommend tackling the perf problem before bringing out the thread canon.  50 milliseconds is a looong time.  This sample code had no effect on interactivity nor made a blip on the cpu load, even though it isn't optimized:

```
    Random rand = new Random();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1)) {
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(rand.Next(800), rand.Next(600), 0, 0, new Size(1, 1));
                Console.WriteLine(bmp.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since UI is STA thread you can't access it froma thread different from the one that created it. Or you can by using "`Control.Invoke`" but in this case it runs upon the message loops so I think you will experience some delay as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Background Worker, and use a timer to call backgroundworker.runasync();.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx